# Default printer changes when another computer on the network prints to specific printer

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer

So I have a problem at a client site.  They have two computers (both Windows 10 Professional) and two printers.  When computer A prints to printer 1 it changes the default printer on computer B to printer 1 instead of printer 2.   As for the setup on how the printers are installed I can look into it if someone needs that information as well as printer models.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Do both computers use a Microsoft account? The default printer settings may be syncing. This post help [Windows 10 Changes my Default Printer Automatically. How to Stop it?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/stop-windows-10-change-default-printer-automatically/)

What I think is happening is. last used printer is becoming the default printer, and this setting is sync'ed to the 2nd PC.

Comment: I will check, but the vast majority of our clients don't use Microsoft accounts as we generally set them up with local accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your printer is shared, which may interfere with a Win10 "feature".

Unless you change settings, Windows 10 will change the default printer to the last one used. I suppose M$ did not envisage that people would ever use more than one printer. To get the normal behaviour, do this:

Open the Settings app.

Go to Settings -> Devices -> Printers and Scanners.
Under the option "Let Windows manage my default printer", set the slider to OFF.

Check this on both computers and see how you go.

Comment: No that was one of the first things we turn off on all of our clients machines.  I can confirm that this isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is remote session IDs. Microsoft (for whatever lame reason) renames printers in remote sessions by appending the words "("Redirected #) with the # being the current session ID. If a user logs off and back on, the session number changes so the label for the printer changes. Because of this changing, Microsoft defaults to the initial printer (Microsoft Print To Pdf). 
One workaround is to have users reboot instead of logging off. This will keep the session number at the lowest nominator (usually 2) and the printer name will not change.
There is no fix for this by Microsoft because this is desired behavior